# Django, How to validate year dependent on another class foreign key

Tags: django, python-3.x, validation, django-models

In Django models i have two classes and I want to validate class Comment date to be less or equal class Report year.

```
class Report(models.Model):
    year = models.PositiveIntegerField('year of report', default=date.today().year)
```

and another class:

```
class Comment():
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment')
    date = models.DateField('date', validators=[year_validation])
```

How can i do this thnig? I discovered something like custom validators. I made a function and used it but how can i get acces to second class here? I wanted to do something like this but it doesn't work.

```
def year_validation(self, value):
    if value.year > self.report.year:
        raise ValidationError('The year should be not later than: {}'.format(self.report.year))
```

Comment: it is better to handle these type of *complex validation* logics in **Model Form**s

Comment: but I need to use it in Django Rest Framework as API, so in serializer would be better?

Comment: In DRF,  we use ***serializers*** instead of *Model Forms*. So, you should write the validation logics in **`validate(...)`** method of corresponding Serializer class